# Stored Procedure Returns int instead of NVARCHAR in sql management studio

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
  Create PROCEDURE GETTABLENAME(@TableId nvarchar(10))
as
begin
declare @TableName nvarchar(150),
        @SQLString nvarchar(4000)

SET @SQLString = N'select  @TableName=sys.tables.name from sys.tables 
        where sys.tables.name like  ''%[_]'+@TableId+'[_]%'' '

exec   sp_executesql @SQLString,
       N'@TableName nvarchar(150) output,  @TableId nvarchar(10) '
       ,@TableId = @TableId
       ,@TableName = @TableName output

return  @TableName  
end
```

When i call inside (not stored procedure) it works perfectly because i use `PRINT` on `@TableName` and gets my result. The problem is when i call this stored procedure it tries to convert result to int and i dunno why?

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'E_GrupBilancoGelirTablosu_935_Form' to data type int
```

Answer (score 5):

The `return` value from a stored procedure is *always* of type `int`. It's meant to be used for success/error codes (old skool error management). If you want something else, look into using [`output` parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx). (Note that a common error when one first starts using `output` parameters is to neglect to use the `OUTPUT` marker in both the parameter list *and* at the call site)

So, something like:

```
Create PROCEDURE GETTABLENAME(
  @TableId nvarchar(10),
  @TableName nvarchar(150) output --Declared as parameter rather than local var
  )
as
begin
declare  @SQLString nvarchar(4000)

SET @SQLString = N'select  @TableName=sys.tables.name from sys.tables 
        where sys.tables.name like  ''%[_]'+@TableId+'[_]%'' '

exec   sp_executesql @SQLString,
       N'@TableName nvarchar(150) output,  @TableId nvarchar(10) '
       ,@TableId = @TableId
       ,@TableName = @TableName output

return  @TableName  
end
```

And then called like:

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(150)
EXEC GETTABLENAME N'abc',@TableName OUTPUT
```

(There's no requirement that the outer variable and the parameter names are identical, they just happen to be in the above example)

Comment: Ok can you fix then, as far as i understand i will not use return in sp but in parameter part i will add output and when i call,i will add declared variable to call rite?

Comment: Also there is absolutely no need in dynamic sql here.